# KendoUI - using something other than $ for jQuery

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I'm looking to integrate some kendoui features into an existing interface. Problem is, that interface uses $j for jquery instead of $. Is there a simple way to make kendoui work using $j instead of $?

Storing a second copy of kendoui just for this purpose isn't realistic, so this would be a deal breaker for us

Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you alias $j to $ ? e.g. $ = $j;

Comment: Kendo UI uses the jQuery alias (window.jQuery). It should work fine if it's available before loading the Kendo UI scripts.

Answer (score 4):

Simply use this snippet of code :

```
window.$j = window.jQuery;
```

That should do the trick.

**Edit:**

After re-reading your question, seems I was half-off-topic.

I guess what I wrote is what you already did.
So just do this once you loaded all your js files :

```
window.kendo.jQuery = window.$j = window.jQuery;
```

Don't hesitate to comment if something seems odd.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to set `kendo.jQuery` to the jQuery of your choice. :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically to remove the $ from the global scope use

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

then assign it to new variable like this

```
$j = jQuery;
```

More info [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).